# Preprocessor Macro for target not working

Tags: swift, xcode, macros, preprocessor

I added a “Preprocessor Macro” `TEST=1` to my Xcode target for all build configurations.

Was expecting I could now use it like this:

```swift
#if TEST
print("testing")
#else
print("not testing")
#endif
```

When running the target the compiler always uses `print("not testing")` though.

I also tried adding a “User-Defined Setting” `OTHER_SWIFT_FLAG` `-DTEST` as well as adding `-DTEST` to “Other Linker Flags”. With the same result.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

Had to use „Active Compilation Conditions”.